# laravel join: How can I join tables and pull various kinds of data according to my conditions form the same join?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel

This is what I have done so far.

```
DB::table('products')
 ->leftjoin('inventories', 'inventories.product_id', 'products.id')
 })
 ->leftjoin('order_items as purchase_oi', function($query){
 $query->on('purchase_oi.inventory_id', 'inventories.id');
  $query->on('purchase_oi.status','!=', \DB::raw('"cancelled"'));
                        })                       
 ->select(DB::raw('sum(inventories.quantity)as qty'),
 DB::raw('count(purchase_oi.inventory_id) as purchases'),                            
  'products.id as pid', 'products.*')                          
  ->where('products.is_deleted', 0)
  ->where('inventories.is_deleted',0)
  ->groupBy('inventories.product_id')                  
  ->get();
```

order_items table contains the status in

```
enum('shipped','return''cancelled');
```

This issue is here on the join with order_items table. Currently, I'm just getting the data which is not equal to cancelled but I want to get the order_items data which are returned and the order_items data which are cancelled.
**i.e get me the purchases,cancelled and return count from order_items table.**
Expected output is:

```
0=>purchases = 4,
   returns = 10,
   cancelled = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is your `groupBy()`.  If you have the following query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM table GROUP BY id
```

You **don't** end up with

```
+-------+
| count |
+-------+
| 5     |
+-------+
```

Instead you end up with:

```
+-------+
| count |
+-------+
| 1     |
+-------+
| 1     |
+-------+
| 1     |
+-------+
| 1     |
+-------+
| 1     |
+-------+
```

The count of all items *per* *grouping*.

Try this:

```
\DB::enableQueryLog();
\DB::flushQueryLog();

//Execute your query

$queries = /DB::getQueryLog();
/DB::disableQueryLog();
/DB::flushQueryLog();

$queries = collect($queries)->map(function (array $query) {
    return array_only($query, ['query', 'bindings']);
})->toArray();

dd($queries);
```

This should tell you exactly what SQL is being executed.

Comment: i've done grouped by it helped me to some extent. But since inventories can have multiple order_items its duplicating the data.. i'm going crazy here.

Comment: Actually, I was suggesting that you remove the `groupBy()`.  `COUNT()` and `MAX()` already aggregate the results for you.  If that's not working, I'd have to take a closer look at your situation.  It may end up being easier to do this as more than one query.

Comment: lets just say there are 5 products. Each products have multiple inventories with quantities. I need to list down the 5 products with their total quantities. In order to do that i should use group By. If i didnt it will give me a single data with all the total of the quantities of the products. Now i have product with their quantities. Now I have get the count of purchase. Lets say a particular inventory item is purchased two times then when i get the count it counts two data but gives me the wrong quantity. If the quantity total was 10 it will give me now 20. Sorry couldnt explain better :(